# Using TabBar with SliverChildListDelegate in Flutter

Tags: flutter, tabbar, sliverappbar

I need to add a TabBar to a screen of my application that I have developed with Flutter, but the place I want to add is at the bottom of the SliverAppBar. How can I do that?

altKisim() contains a Column.

```
Column(
children:[
Widget..
Divider(),
--This is where I want to add--
Widget..
],
);
```

[image]

Is there a way to add to this code snippet or do I have to completely change the build? Because all the solutions I found suggest that I need to change it.

Comment: i tested using `TabBarView` but the problem comes it need to provide height and in this case we will lose some controls over appBar. i think `NestedScrollView` may suit here. also, if you add 2 3 text inside `flexibleSpace`, we can use bottom property there.

Comment: @YeasinSheikh Can you share a short sample code please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sample from conversation

```
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  get tabView => [
        ...List.generate(
          3,
          (index) => Container(
            height: 700,
            color: index.isEven ? Colors.deepPurple : Colors.deepOrange,
            child: Text("index $index"),
          ),
        ).toList(),
      ];

  int _currentIndex = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: LayoutBuilder(
        builder: (context, constraints) => CustomScrollView(
          slivers: [
            SliverAppBar(
              title: Text("AppBar"),
              expandedHeight: 300,
              floating: true,
              flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
                background: Container(
                  color: Colors.cyanAccent,
                  child: Column(
                    children: [Text("asdasd")],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            SliverToBoxAdapter(
              child: tabView[_currentIndex],
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        showSelectedLabels: false,
        showUnselectedLabels: false,
        currentIndex: _currentIndex,
        onTap: (index) {
          setState(() {
            _currentIndex = index;
          });
        },
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home),
            label: "Home",
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.ac_unit),
            label: "AC",
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.umbrella),
            label: "umbrella",
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Does it solve in your case?

Comment: Tab Bar buttons should be at the bottom, not inside the Flexible Space Bar. As seen in the picture I shared.

Comment: that will be `bottomNavigationBar` in this case, i updated the answer